# php try catch with database query not catcing error

Tags: php

I am trying to catch error mechanism with php but it does not return $dataTable on exceptions. if pg_quey gives error, it prints error message on screen.

```
    try{
        $queryResult = pg_query($this->connection, $query_string);


        while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($queryResult)){
            $dataTable[] = $row;
        }

        return $dataTable[0];            

    }catch (Exception $ex){
        return $dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe because that method doesn't throw an exception on error? What does the error message say? Is it `Uncaught exception` or something else?

Comment: Are you setting `$dataTable` somewhere? If it's not set, it can't return it.

Comment: According to [pg_query manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) it doesn't throw an exception, rather returns `false` if something goes wrong.

Comment: on catch it can't return $dataTable if you don't set it before. Try to return $ex